# rmarkdown includes don't work when in_header files in subdir

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

Adding `in_header: pre.sty` to the `yaml` content includes the file as expected when pre.sty exists in the same directory as the rmarkdown file. However, using `in_header: etc\pre.sty` along with moving `pre.sty` to a subdirectory fails with error:

```
File etc\pre.sty not found in resource path
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 99
Execution halted
```

is there a way to incorporate header files stored in subdirectories or does this appear to be a bug? I have attempted variations on the approach, but none have been successful.

Minimal example:

```
---
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    # will be generated by includes s
    toc: no
    fig_align: center
    fig_height: 4
    fig_width: 6
    latex_engine: xelatex
    keep_tex: true
    includes:
      in_header: pre.sty
fontsize: 11pt
---

Min example 1 - this works when pre.sty is stored in same dir as rmarkdown.
```

Minimal example:

```
---
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    # will be generated by includes s
    toc: no
    fig_align: center
    fig_height: 4
    fig_width: 6
    latex_engine: xelatex
    keep_tex: true
    includes:
      in_header: etc\pre.sty
fontsize: 11pt
---

Min example 2 - this does not work when pre.sty is stored in the etc subdir.
```

Contents of `pre.sty`

```
\usepackage{booktabs}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the forward slash: `etc/pre.sty`.